# How many elements will be in the primary storage area array, if the nodes are stored using a direct hashing function

Tags: java, arrays, hash

I am trying to figure out how I can use the division hashing function to calculate the number elements will be in the primary storage area array if objects are to be stored in a data structure each have 1000 bytes of information, which includes the key field comprised of 5 digits and a maximum of 1500 nodes will be in the structure at one time. I know that in order to find the number of elements, would I have to something like this:

**h(k)= k % number of elements in the array** so would it be like 12345 % 1500, but this doesn't produce a whole number. I am just trying to figure this out. Here is my online resource that I have researched before asking this question: 
https://modernpathshala.com/Learn/data-structure/Tutorial/8438/divison-hashfunction

Comment: Hashtables can (and do) have collisions, so you don't need a whole number.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Wouldn't I have to know the actual key in order to do this calculation?

Comment: modulo operator `%` on integer operands produces positive int numbers.  So, you should be all set.

Comment: @Serge So what I have done is correct? It's not supposed to be a density answer; I would think my final answer would be bigger. Am I not following the function right?

Comment: @Serge Are you still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple idea of a hash table is to have an array of a known number of elements. Every array element is an access point to the data records.

The index in the array is determined from the key using some simple method. Ideally the search will be N time faster than the linear search, where N is the array size. But it will only be so, if you distribute your data equally over all array entries. Also, every key should produce the same array index.

Hash functions play a big role in providing a linear distribution of keys across array elements. Without it you risk ending up with a hash table where your keys only hit a small number of the array entries significantly crippling search performance.

Now, usually the array size is much smaller than the number of data you want to insert. This means that different keys could be mapped to the same array index. So, you would need to provide an additional mechanism to find a correct element there. In this sense you would need to know the real key to do this search. Also, the opposite is true, if the key produces an array index, there is no guarantee that your data is there. You still need to do an additional search.

Hash tables use normal non-associative array with integer indexing. So, all operations on indexes should result in discrete  'int' data types. If you look into your guidelines, the 'hash' function produces an 'int' value from the key. The simplest way to get an array index from this hash is to use the '%' operator.  It produces a reminder of division. So, if you do `hash % N` where `N` is the size of the array, you will always get a value from `0` to the last element of the array `N - 1`. This would be your index.

```
int hash = hash_function(key);
int index = hash % N;  // 12345 % 1500 = 8 -- from your question
```

The above index will become an integer value of 8, which will be use in insertion and search.

Comment: @Serge-So this tells which index to map the key to, but how would we find the number of elements? The number of elements definitely would be greater than 8, right because we have started out with large number of nodes stored in this array.

Comment: i understand that you want to find an index for each key in an array, but when we go to calculate the density using a formula like this        n * w / (n * w + 4N) N would definitely be larger, right? Or else the density probably won't be calculated right for direct hash structure, correct?

Comment: number of entries in the table? you either pick it manually, usually using prime numbers for better distribution, i.e. 101, or use some heuristic, based on the expected number of data and performance. It does not depend on the size of data you use, but rather on the number of keys. Some implementations allow you to increase the size of the table if it becomes too full.

Comment: i usually use a rule o thumb, i.e. number of entries should be no less than number of elements/ 4, i.e. 4 keys per entry. This have worked for me for the most tasks. You might find tons of different recommendations.

Comment: Isn't number of entries in the table the same as number of elements?

Comment: @Serge-Sorry about that. So for the division hashing function, the number of elements would be 4k+3 prime?

Comment: @Serge-So I thinking to calculate N you would have Nmax (max number of nodes in the structure) * p (0.33) + (max number of nodes in the structure) = 1500 + 1500 * 0.33 = 1,995 but the next higher prime than this is 2003 (N) Then you just substitute that into the equation for the density. I am right?

Comment: Sounds like you trying to have your table larger than the number of nodes you want to store. It could be reasonable from performance point of view but will use more memory.  I have no idea if you are right or wrong, it depends on your goal.